# NetBeans: How to provide offline XML schemas?

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd

I would like to have the code completion and XML validation that comes from NetBeans having access to the schemas referenced in XML documents.  Unfortunately I need to use NetBeans in an offline (completely disconnected from the Internet) location, meaning NetBeans fails in downloading the referenced .xsd files.  However, I have all of the xsd files saved locally.

How can I make NetBeans know that something like `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"`
 should really map to `C:/Schemas/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd`?

Edit:
NetBeans 6.5 has some means of having an XML catalog of schemas, but it's unclear how this works.  I know one of the options is for [OASIS](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/specs/cs-entity-xml-catalogs-1.0.html#s.intro) format... perhaps this is the key

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do the following in NetBeans 6.9...

1. Select the 'DTDs and XML Schemas'
   item from the Tools menu.

   A dialog box will open.
2. Scroll through the list on the left
   until the item 'User catalog
   [read-write] is visible.

   Select that item.
3. Press the button titled 'Add Local
   DTD or Schema...'

   Another dialog opens to define a
   connection between a URL with a
   reference to a local file.

Comment: This worked beautifully.  I had seen that dialog but I missed the fact that there was a "User catalog [read-write]" element.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Using schemaLocation, if I use the URL as SYSTEM,  NetBeans doesn't use the file given in URI.