# Look for Java Spring XML Catalog (for modern 3.x and old 2.x version of Spring)

Tags: java, spring, xsd, xmlcatalog

For XML tags/attributes completion in NetBeans I need XML Catalog for Java Spring (for modern 3.x and old 2.x version of Spring).

Where can I found it?

Reference:

- [NetBeans: How to provide offline XML schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579413/netbeans-how-to-provide-offline-xml-schemas)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog

Could you help me?

Comment: **question updated** I need XML Catalog for Java Spring XSD files...